# Is there an amphibian mass die off and if so, what is causing it?

Tags: extinction-event

http://frogmatters.wordpress.com/2009/02/20/scientists-scramble-to-solve-amphibian-death-puzzle/

Are there thousands of species dying off due to a chitrid fungus?  I tend to be very skeptical of this (for instance, how does one even track the number of frogs there are in something like a rain forest).

Comment: At least tell me what's wrong...

Comment: Welcome to Skeptics.SE! We expect askers to put a bit more effort into their questions than simply posting a link: add context, tell us what you already know, cite the most relevant parts of the page you linked to in your question, etc. It will help us provide you with a better answer.

Comment: What are you asking exactly? This seems like a good topic for the site, but this is not a forum - we answer specific questions. I suggest you put your post in the form: useful context with links, then one specific, objectively answerable question.

Comment: If i recall correctly, someone was well on the way to proving that the most likely vector for the transmission of the fungus between frog populations was the researchers themselves. Can't link now though, on my phone.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decline_in_amphibian_populations) on this subject, which has a lot of
references that seem to be of high quality. You can also go to
[amphibiaweb.org](http://amphibiaweb.org/declines/declines.html) or the [national biological information
infrastructure](http://www.nbii.gov/portal/server.pt/community/amphibian_declines/387).

The "killer fungus" is not the only cause these sources mention. Other causes
include habitat modification and fragmentation, pollution and climatic
change.

It's certainly possible to count numbers of amphibians and it is not
necessary to count them all to know that there is a dramatic decline in
their numbers. If a sufficiently large number of populations around the
world is counted accurately over a long enough period, and those
populations are seen to decrease in numbers all over the world, I would say
it is safe to speak of a global decline in amphibian populations.

Concerning the causes and what we can know about them: we can study the
data, e.g. look at whether there are differences in decline rates between
different types of populations (cool or warm climate, human density, food
sources, amount of pollution), and we can study the effects something like
the fungus has on individual amphibians, or on populations.

It's fairly easy to find a lot of information on this topic, from pretty
reliable sources. I don't think skepticism is warranted here.

Comment: I've been skeptical of claims that a single fungus is responsible for extinctions in several separated populations.